# Passing php variables as arguments in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am new in php.Instead of using

```
$result=mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)
$result['id'];
```

i want to pass a variable instead of `id` like this

```
$id='id';
$result=mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)
    $result[$id];
```

I have tried like this but not working.How can i pass a variable as argument to fetch a value from database

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php   that page has all you want to know about it. Also this: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: I cant understand that thing.

Comment: @Root, If you are using PHP5.5 then every function that starts with `mysql_` will generates error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_assoc` provides you the multi-dimentional array.

```
$result = array(
    array('id'=>`some_value`)
);
```

So you can do like this:

```
$ID = "id";
foreach($result as $row) {
    echo $row[$ID] . "\n";
}
```

### NOTE:

[Please, don't use mysql_* functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).